# Semaphore wait on event triggered windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, deadlock, semaphore

I have implemented a buffer. The buffer has two properties read and write. The read function call waits on read_slot semaphore to be available. The write function call waits on write_slot. The write_slot semaphore is installed to initial count 100 and max count 100 whereas the read slot initialized to initial count 0 and max count 100.

So I fire an event to write on buffer --> decrease the write slot --> increase the read slot. The event is fired very fast sometimes.
The read operation decrease the read_slot and increase the write_slot.
Hence, this architecture cannot face a deadlock--> as deadlock occurs only when the read_slot is 0 and write_slot is 0... which is impossible as slots are increased and decrease within common mutex lock.

Still I am facing a deadlock situation. Do anyone have any idea regarding the functionality of event triggered system.

Comment: Why not post some code so people can take a look and offer advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
  The event is fired very fast sometimes.
```

Why don't you use Producer Consumer pattern.
Obviously, You can't read without write (Read operation should takes place after write operation).
You can achieve this in .Net easily by [BlockingCollections](http://www.codethinked.com/blockingcollection-and-iproducerconsumercollection).

Comment: sorry to mention .... I am using IPC producer consumer in 'C' and I have also used signals to wake up read/write process. most probably that's causing some asynchronous behaviour. I have removed sleep from both reader and writer for now and they are busy waiting in infinite loop..... its working... but I need a sleeping producer consumer... can't implement kernel semaphore for IPC synchronization as they have their own limitations.

Comment: Are you implementing IPC in C or C# ? what you intend to do with C# ? if C#, we have sleeping/waiting producer consumer (not infinite loop). Or better put some code (your requirement is not clear)